# Height function following Borel

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

Borel introduces the notion of *hauteur* (French for 'height') in a note titled

*Sur l'approximation les uns par les autres des nombres formant un ensemble dénombrable*

in the Comptes Rendus journal in 1903.

To my own surprise, Borel's notion of *hauteur* is exactly what we call 'height' today: for a countable set of reals $A$, a *height function* $H$ is such that $\{ x \in A: H(x)<n\}$ is finite for all natural $n$.  Height functions [are used to show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_function#Other_height_functions) that there is a bijection between the natural and rational numbers.

Was Borel the first one to come up with height functions, or are there earlier known instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As usual, it is very difficult to identify the first occurrence of a term, but in this case it is Borel's own article that can help us.

The full note can be found [here](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-3091&I=297&M=tdm), we read:

> Étant donné un ensemble dénombrable $E$ de nombres réels, nous ferons correspondre à chaque nombre de l'ensemble un entier positif $h$ que nous appelerons *hauteur* de ce nombre dans $E$ et tel que chaque valeur de $h$ corresponde à un nombre limité de nombres de $E$. Une telle correspondance peut être obtenue d'une infinité de manières [...]

i.e.

> Given a countable set $E$ of real numbers, we will map to each number in the set a positive integer $h$, which we will call *height* of that number in $E$, such that each value of $h$ corresponds to a finite number of numbers in $E$. Such a correspondence can be obtained in an infinite number of ways [...]

Borel says "nous ferons correspondre", that is "we will map to", using the first person plural and providing no bibliographical reference (which he generally does), thus suggesting that it is his own definition.

A little further on we read:

> Je me propose de résumer d'abord quelques recherches, que je publierai prochainement, relatives à la *détermination effective* de la fonction $\varphi(h_1,h_2)$ pour certains ensembles $E$; j'indiquerai ensuite quel intéret il me paraitrait y avoir à la déterminer dans des cas de plus en plus généraux.

i.e.

> First, I'll summarize some research I'll be publishing shortly into the *effective determination* of the function $\varphi(h_1,h_2)$ [a positive lower bound for the difference $|x_1-x_2|$ where $x_1$ and $x_2$ have height $h_1$ and $h_2$, respectively] for certain sets $E$; then I'll indicate the interest I see in determining it in increasingly general cases.

So once again the impression is that Borel is reporting personal considerations. The most interesting part is as follows.

> Dans le travaux antérieurs sur l'approximation des incommensurables, on supposait que le nombre $x_1$ appartenait à un ensemble $E_1$, le nombre $x_2$ à l'ensemble $E_2$ des nombres rationnels, et l'on cherchait une limitation asymptotiques de $\varphi(h_1,h_2)$ lorsque, $h_1$ étant fixe, $h_2$ croissait indéfiniment; tels sont les résultats de Liouville, de M. Maillet, de M. Störmer; dans ma Note précité, j'ai étudié le cas d'un ensemble $E$ formé des nombres algébrique, mais j'ai supposé aussi $x_1$ fixe et cherché seulement une limitation asymptotique de $\varphi(h_1,h_2)$; pour les applications, il y a un grand intéret à se placer au nouveau point de vue que je viens d'indiquer, cau une inégalité asymptotique est souvent peu utile lorsque l'on ne sait pas à partir de quelle valeur de la variable elle est vérifiée.

i.e.

> In earlier work on the approximation of incommensurables, it was assumed that the number $x_1$ belonged to a set $E_1$, the number $x_2$ to the set $E_2$ of rational numbers, and an asymptotic limitation of $\varphi(h_1,h_2)$ was sought when, $h_1$ being fixed, $h_2$ grew indefinitely; such are the results of Liouville, Mr Maillet, Mr Störmer; in my aforementioned Note [see below], I studied the case of a set $E$ made up of algebraic numbers, but I also assumed $x_1$ to be fixed and sought only an asymptotic limitation of $varphi(h_1,h_2)$; for applications, there is great interest in taking the new point of view I have just indicated, as an asymptotic inequality is often of little use when we don't know from which value of the variable it is verified.

Here we are explicitly talking about a new point of view compared to previous research, and also compared to the author's own research. The note cited is thet of Mars, 6, 1899, *[Sur la nature aritmétique du nombre $e$](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k30841/f596.item.r=borel)*, where no explicit reference is made to height; another relavant work of Borel is *Leçons sur la théorie des fonctions*, [Chapter II](https://archive.org/details/leconstheoriefon00borerich/page/n33/mode/2up).
The works of Störmer are *[Quelques propriétés arithmétiques des intégrales elliptiques et leurs applications a la théorie des fonctions entières transcendantes](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-27/issue-none/Quelques-propri%C3%A9t%C3%A9s-arithm%C3%A9tiques-des-int%C3%A9grales-elliptiques-et-leurs-applications-a/10.1007/BF02421305.full)* and *[Sur une propriété arithmétique des logarithmes des nombres algébriques](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/bsmf.628.pdf)*; as in the case of Borel's work previously cited, there is no direct reference to the term height.
The relevant works of Maillet are *[Sur les équations différentielles rationnelles](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-3089&I=782&M=tdm)*, *[Sur les équations et les nombres transcendants](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-3089&I=1190&M=tdm)*, *[Sur les équations différentielles et la théorie
des ensembles](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/bsmf.672.pdf)*, and *[Sur les nombres e et p et les équations transcendantes](http://visualiseur.bnf.fr/CadresFenetre?O=NUMM-3089&I=1190&M=tdm)*.

In conclusion, judging from Borel's way of expressing himself in the quoted passages and again in other places in his note (toward the end, it is suggested that the concept of height be generalized to the case of complex numbers as well), it seems that the term was precisely introduced by Borel, with the idea of generalizing approaches previously proposed by other authors and by Borel himself.

However, this still does not tell us where exactly Borel got the idea of introducing the concept of height from. Again, Borel's article itself gives us some clues. Toward the end we read:

> Si l'on construit l'analyse en partant de *l'unité*, la définition d'un nombre quelconque exige un certain nombre d'opération élémentaires , [...] l'hauteur $h$ d'un nombre $x$ [...] est en relation simples avec le nombre d'opérations élémentaires au moyen desquelles on peut définir $x$ [...]

i.e.

> If we construct the analysis starting from *unity*, the definition of any number requires a certain number of elementary operations, [...] the height $h$ of a number $x$ [...] is in simple relation to the number of elementary operations by means of which $x$ can be defined [...].

This sibylline statement is made more clearly in a later work, *[Contribution à l'analyse arithmétique du continu](http://www.numdam.org/item/JMPA_1903_5_9__329_0.pdf)* (this work deserves to be restarted almost in its entirety, below I will select only a few passages):

> Toutes les Mathématiques peuvent se déduire de la seule notion
> de nombre entier [...] [c]e nouveau point de vue peut être caractérisé par le fait que l'on ne fait jamais intervenir dans
> chaque question qu'un *nombre limité de nombres entiers* au moyen
> desquels tous les éléments de la question sont explicitement définis [...] Si l'on considère ainsi un nombre (rationnel, algébrique ou transcendant) caractérisé par un certain nombre d'entiers et par certaines opérations [...] La complication de chaque nombre peut être ainsi caractérisée numériquement [...] le nombre
> ou symbole qui mesurera cette complication sera dit la hauteur du
> nombre dans le système considéré.

i.e.

> All Mathematics can be deduced from the notion of integers alone [...] [t]his new point of view can be characterized by the fact that each question never involves more than a *limited number of integers*, by means of which all the elements of the question are explicitly defined [...] If we thus consider a number (rational, algebraic or transcendental) characterized by a certain number of integers and by certain operations [...] The complication of each number can thus be characterized numerically. If we thus consider a number (rational, algebraic or transcendental) characterized by a certain number of integers and by certain operations [...] The complication of each number can thus be characterized numerically [...] the number or symbol that measures this complication is said to be the height of the number in the system considered.

Borel himself in a footnote lets us know that this idea of height is essentially due to [Jules Drach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jules_Drach) (with whom Borel had written in the 1895 *[Introduction à l'Étude de la Théorie des Nombres et de l'Algèbre Supérieure](https://archive.org/details/introletudetheor00borerich/page/n7/mode/2up)*), and is found in particular in *Introduction à la Théorie des nombres et de l'Algèbre supérieure* and in his thesis *[Essai sur la théorie générale de l'intégration et sur la classification des transcendantes](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/asens.457.pdf)*. However, according to Borel, in the works cited above, Drach applies this idea only to the study of differential equations and partial derivatives, whereas instead one should use this concept to address problems concerning transcendental numbers and functions more generally. Nonetheless, it is Borel himself who states that this observation is also due to Drach.